# return false unless phone number matches correct format

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I want the code to return false unless phoneNumber matches the proper format.

```
def validPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  return false unless phoneNumber
  return false unless phoneNumber.length == 14
  ## return false unless phoneNumber.include? "(,)' ' -"

  return phoneNumber
end
```

So, for example:

```
validPhoneNumber("(552) 555-1048")
# false
```

How can I check to see if phoneNumber contains any of the special characters like `(`, `)` and `-`?

Should I use a regexp here?

Comment: write a regexp i.e. `return false if /\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}/ !~ phoneNumber`

Comment: What are the allowed characters for a phone number?

Comment: @Малъ's regex will not match if the phone number does not have 14 characters, so there's no need to check the length.

Comment: If you don't mind returning `nil` rather than `false` when the string is not a valid phone number (which should [not be a problem](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/)), `validPhoneNumber` can consist of a single line that uses [String#\[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with @Малъ's regex: `phoneNumber[ /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/ ]`.  You should have a look at Ruby's [naming convention](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a regexp:

```
return false if /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/ !~ phoneNumber
```